# Showing element in html with flask and BeautifulSoup 3 and Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, html, flask, beautifulsoup, function

The question is: 
I have my @app.route and the relative def() which shows a list of urls taken from "http://annotaria.web.cs.unibo.it/documents/".
How can i show this urls in a html format? When i click `http://localhost:5000/articoli` i'd like to show a list of my urls.

Thank you very much

```
@app.route('/articoli', methods=['GET'])
def lista_articoli():
lista = []
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = urllib2.urlopen`http://annotaria.web.cs.unibo.it/documents/.read()`
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
for row in soup.findAll('a'):
    if row.parent.name == 'td':
        if row["href"] :
            myArticle = row["href"]
            if '.html' in myArticle:
                print myArticle
                lista.append({'url':myArticle}) }
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Why is showing a list of URLs any different from any other document that you would generate in flask?

Comment: Yes, I wish an html document generated by flask with a list of those urls..

Comment: And, what exactly is your issue? Do you know how to create pages normally with Flask?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, have your function return the `render_template` method, to which you'll pass your URL list.

At the end of your function, try:

```
render_template("articoli.html", lista = lista)
```

You'll need to have a corresponding `articoli.html` template saved in a *templates* folder, which in turn should be in the same location as your Python script. Within the HTML of the template, you'll need to designate where Flask/Jinja puts the URL list you've provided, which in this case would be `{{lista}}`.

This is outlined in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/).